# Regex to turn url into a clean page title

Tags: php, regex

I use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get this `/res/about_us.php`, I want the output to be `About Us`, I know I can use `preg_replace` for this, it is the regular expression I am struggling with.

I have this pitiful attempt thus far:

```
echo str_replace('.php', '', $uri);
```

I realised after this that I cant replace two cases using str_replace... So I thought I need preg_replace with regex, but not a clue how it works, cant seem to find a similar example through Google.

Regards

Comment: It's possible without using regex. show your try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without regular expressions you can do:

```
// Get the filename, e.g., 'about_us'.
$filename = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
// Replace underscore with spaces and capitalise words
$title = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $filename));
```

See [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php), [`ucwords`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can replace multiple cases with `str_replace` by passing an array of things you'd like to replace as first parameter of the function! Something like this:

```
echo ucwords(str_replace(array('_', '-', '.php'), ' ', basename($uri)));
```

Inside the array you could put whatever you'd like to replace.